# search is not working in gridview while using multiple models yii

Tags: php, search, yii, cgridview

I am trying to access 2 related models in one CGridView interface for searching elements. But as soon as I join the second table to the first, search stops working and do not filter anything (the grid is unchanged). I have referred to many links but could not solve this problem myself.

Tables are -
UserMaster (user_id, name, status, ...)
CustomerMaster (customer_id, user_id, account_number,...)

```
usermaster model content -

public $account_number;
public function rules()
{

return array(
        array('name', 'required'),
        array('account_number', 'safe'),
        array('user_id, name,status, account_number', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
}
public function relations()
{
     return array('customer_master' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'CustomerMaster', 'user_id'),);
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
return array(
    'user_id' => 'User',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'status' => 'Status',
    'account_number' => 'Account Number',
    );
}
public function search()
{
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 't';
    $criteria->compare('t.user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('t.name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('t.status',$this->status);
    $criteria->with = 'customer_master';                    
    $criteria->condition = 't.user_type=2';
    $criteria->together = true;

    $criteria->compare('customer_master.user_id',$this->user_id,true);
    if ($this->account_number){
    $criteria->compare('customer_master.account_number',$this->account_number,true);
        }
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>25),
            'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'t.user_id DESC',
            ),
        ));
}

customermaster model content-
public function relations()
{
    return array(

    'user_id' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserMaster', 'user_id'),

    );
}

usermaster controller code -
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new UserMaster('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['UserMaster']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['UserMaster'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
}

admin.php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-master-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array ( 
        'name' => 'customer_master.account_number',
        'header' => 'Account Number',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value'=>'$data->customer_master->account_number',
        ),
        'name',
        'status',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

By joining the above 2 models i am able to get the grid view as expected but search is not working for all the fields.

Someone please help me in identifying the problem. I hope i have explained problem clearly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/ ?

Comment: yes i read it, but could not identify the problem in my code.. actually the code is not showing any errors... simply the search is not working..

Comment: You should read more carefully and modify your related columns definition, and attributes rules

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your yii application logs?  You should be able to see what SQL is being generated and run for this search and then run it manually in your SQL frontend (phpMyAdmin or whatever you prefer to use).

I would imagine the fault lies somewhere with the join between your 2 tables...